# Why am I able to post on Meta despite having < 5 reputation

Tags: support, reputation, meta, privileges

Because of five downvotes to a question that I posted, I only have a reputation total of 1.

However, I was still given access to Meta, which I understood required 5 reputation.

Why is this? Is there a bug in the authorization code, or did I misunderstand something?

Comment: can you be specific? what privilege do you think needs 5 rep that you can still perform?

Answer (score 8):

From the [privileges help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/participate-in-meta):

> ### Why do I need 5 rep to post there?
>
> The following applies to all per-site Metas *except Stack Overflow*. You
>   do not need Stack Overflow reputation to post on its Meta, and your
>   rep on its Meta isn't tied to the parent site.

Answer (score 8):

You always have access to Meta Stack Overflow - it's special, as network requests go here. The 5-rep barrier is only for per-site metas.